# Is it possible to cast on tv using ExoPlayer Library to play stream?

Tags: java, android

I'm working lately on a streaming project, and I'm wondering for the ability to cast/mirror the stream on a Smart TV, just like YouTube function, but instead using ExoPlayer library.

I don't have any attempts, I'm just asking for guidance and if it's possible or not.

Comment: Were you able to achieve something?

Comment: Nope, just ditched the library... couldn't make it to work